# Why are three of the five base location choices unavailable?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

In XCOM: Enemy Unknown, I have to pick the location for my base after the initial tutorial mission. North America and Europe are available, but Asia, South America, and Africa are not.

There's no explanation for why, though. Do I need to play through a game to enable them? Is it a difficulty level thing? How do I build my alien-fighting empire from those locations?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You only get two choices if you are playing the tutorial. However, if you start a new game that skips the tutorial, you can choose from any of the 5 bases. You do not need to beat the game or anything like that first.

Comment: I hate it that implies the 2 options offered are easier to start in (at least for new players)?

Comment: @BenBrocka I used to always start in Europe in X-Com: UFO Defense, so I'm not too broken up about it, but it does seem a bit weird.

Comment: Honestly Africa with the 30% bonus seems the most flexible for a newbie.

Comment: @Sterno I'd have to agree, and considering how tight money is, that extra 30% is a pretty good bonus.

Comment: @AnnaLear hate = take. I accidentally the predicate

Comment: However, Europe and Asia are the hardest bonuses to get through satellites (more countries in them), so if your goal is to get more bonuses fast, those two might be good starting options.